Java ThreadPoolExecutor - FixedThreadPool ActiveCount = 0, QueueSize = 1, PoolSize = 10
I am creating Java thread pool using FixedThreadPool with a pool size of 10.
From the constructor, it is
    public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                      0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                      new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }

That means I created a thread pool with core thread pool size 10 and maximum thread pool size of 10. According to the Java 8 official doc, this means that:

There will be a maximum of 10 threads, regardless how much requests coming in
The queue will grow indefinitely

When checking the counters however, I got confused with the following counter:

ActiveCount = 0
PoolSize = 10
QueueSize = 1

The above counter show up a coupe of times so it is not just an one off situation. I also see some counters like this:

ActiveCount = 1
PoolSize = 10
QueueSize = 1

In this case a request is still in the queue while there are less than pool size of threads are actively processing tasks. Does anyone know why this happen? Am I missing anything here?

I can duplicate the issue by adding threads quickly enough that it seems to overwhelm the input queue somehow.  Whatever the "run" mechanism is it seems to queue up tasks first, then check if a queued task needs a thread.  The synchronization there might slow things down enough that new tasks are stored for a bit while the executor launches a new thread.  I'm guessing but that's what I got.

@markspace Thanks for replicate this issue. Do you also see active count really low in this case? What does not make sense to me is the active account - I always feel it can be substantially higher.

Yes, I can put 20 tasks in the queue and have only 2 active threads sometimes.  I think it's also due to the time each task takes.  I think very short tasks (like a micro-benchmark, or maybe a poorly designed application) could end so quickly that later tasks are assigned an existing thread rather than increasing the thread count.  I'm only guessing, but that how I feel it might work.

In support of that idea, I added a Thread.sleep(2000) to my test code and then all 10 threads in the executor are present.

I don't really see the problem here. Are you suggesting that there should be no queue as long as the active count is less than 10? How are you checking this? Nothing that you have shown in the javadoc would contradict this. A task is added to the queue, then a thread will take it from the queue and work on it.

This is an artefact due to race conditions.
If you look at the example that markspace provided:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
       System.out.println(es);
       for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
          es.execute(() -> System.out.println("test"));
       }
       System.out.println(es);
       es.shutdown();
    }

It creates a fixed threadpool of size 10 and then submits 20 tasks in short succession.
For the first 10 tasks worker threads are created and started immediately, the other 10 tasks are added to the work queue.
That 10 worker threads are created is shown by the "pool size = 10":

Before submitting the first task, printing the status of the thread pool prints "pool size = 0"
After submitting tasks, print the status of the thread pool prints "pool size = 10"

When you print out the state of the thread pool using System.out.println(es); the thread pools toString() method gathers some statistics:

Returns a string identifying this pool, as well as its state, including indications of run state and estimated worker and task counts.

These values are not exact because the toString() method does not pause any workers while gathering the statistics.

A worker currently executing a task counts as "active"
A worker that has finished a task and is fetching the next task is not active
looping over the list of workers is faster than workers fetching tasks from the task queue (since looping over the list doesn't involve any locking, fetching tasks from the task queue needs locking)
Therefore some of the workers that have just completed a tasks and are in the state of fetching the next task are not s


Thanks for the explanation Thomas! The "estimated" part is what I missed.

I don't know if this is a "good" answer, but I'll add it since seems a little inobvious.
When I test the OP's code with a very short test case (task), I get results similar to the OP's.  This could be considered a common problem with micro-benchmarks.  Or it could also be a problem with poorly designed production code, sending very short tasks to a separate thread for execution.  For example:
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 );
      System.out.println( es );
      for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
         es.execute( () -> {System.out.println( "test" ); } );
//         es.execute( FixedThreadPool::test );
      System.out.println( es );
      es.shutdown();
   }

Produces output like this:
test
test
test
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7506e922[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 10, completed tasks = 8]
test
test
test (more "test" lines removed)

On the other hand if I add a longer delay to the test task, for example a 2 second sleep delay, then all 10 threads in the executor show as active.
public class FixedThreadPool {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 );
      System.out.println( es );
      for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
         es.execute( FixedThreadPool::test );
      System.out.println( es );
      es.shutdown();
   }

   private static void test() {
      try {
         System.out.println( "test" );
         Thread.sleep( 2000 );
      } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
         // exit
      }
   }
}

Output:
test
test
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7506e922[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 10, completed tasks = 0]
test
test
test (more "test" lines trimmed)


Thanks Mark! I think that makes sense. The metrics I put in the question is per second I did some calculation and find that statistically it is possible that every time when a counter is emitted there are no active tasks. Your investigation really helps a lot here!
